# PropertiesFactoryBean vs @PropertySource

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations, properties-file

I need to read menu.properties file only in the class MyServiceImpl.java
These values are not Environment specific.

```
menu.properties
----------------
menu.option=option1,option2,option3
```

1)using @PropertySource

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.test.*" })
@PropertySource("classpath:menu.properties")
public class MyServiceImpl{

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    public List<String> createMenu(){
       String menuItems = env.getProperty("menu.option");
...}
}
```

2) How to access the below bean in MyServiceImpl.java

```
<bean id="properties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:menu.properties"/>
</bean>
```

Which approach do I need to follow and what is the difference between PropertiesFactoryBean and PropertySource?

Comment: Did you try 
`@Autowired
PropertiesFactoryBean pfb;`
?

Comment: @user2893856 Just wondering if it helped?

Answer (score 2):

**Use of Environment:**
Environment provides convenient interface for providing property sources. The properties can be loaded from jvm args, system variables, property file etc. Using env provides better abstraction IMHO.

Given a choice i would prefer `Environment` as it provides better abstraction. Instead of properties files you can load from jvm arguments or system variables tomorrow, the interface is going to remain the same.

*To answer you second question (I have provided short form as well).*

**Long form:**

```
<bean id="properties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:menu.properties"/>
</bean>
```

**Short form:**

```
<util:properties id="properties" location="classpath:menu.properties"/>

public class MyServiceImpl{

    @Autowired
    private Properties properties;
    public List<String> createMenu(){
       String menuItems = properties.getProperty("menu.option");
...}
}
```

**Third option**

If you going to read properties directly and if there are not environment specific, i would suggest using `<context:property-placeholder>` which registers PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:menu.properties" />
```

if you declare as above, you can directly read values using `@value` annotation as below.

```
public class MyServiceImpl{

    @value("${menu.option}")
    String menuItems;

    public List<String> createMenu(){
       //use items directly;
...}

}
```